# Missing dunders for list type in attrs.asdict()?

Tags: python, python-attrs

I was trying to create a nesting of `list()` class using Python `attrs` decoractors, and noticed that the `attrs.asdict()` did not work at some level of subvariables.  Such that:

- `attrs.asdict(mlle)` displays ok
- `attrs.asdict(mlle.list_of_list_of_elements)` # FAILS
- `attrs.asdict(mlle.list_of_list_of_elements[0])` displays ok

My working example is:

```py
import attr


@attr.s
class MyElement(object):
    element = attr.ib(default="mydefault", type=str)

@attr.s(slots=True)
class MyListOfElements(object):
    one_element = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(MyElement))
    list_of_elements = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list), type=list)
    def add(self, le):
        self.list_of_elements.append(le)

@attr.s(slots=True)
class MyListOfList(object):
    version = attr.ib(default=None, type=str)
    list_of_list_of_elements = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list))  # Where's the dunder for this list?

e1 = MyElement("1.1.1.1")
e1_1 = MyElement("11.11.11.11")
le1 = MyListOfElements()
le1.add(e1)
le1.add(e1_1)
print("le1:", le1)

e2 = MyElement("2.2.2.2")
le2 = MyListOfElements(e2)
le2.list_of_elements.append(e2)
print("le2:", le2)

mlle = MyListOfList()
print("mlle:", mlle)
mlle.list_of_list_of_elements.append(le1)
mlle.list_of_list_of_elements.append(le2)
print("mlle:", mlle)
```

Now onward to using the `attr.asdict()` function...

```
# attr.Dict
print("asdict(mlle):", attr.asdict(mlle))
print("asdict(mlle.lle):", attr.asdict(mlle.list_of_list_of_elements))  # FAILS
print("asdict(mlle.lle[0]):", attr.asdict(mlle.list_of_list_of_elements[0]))
```

I am quite sure that I did something simple incorrectly as I thought I decorated ALL the nested variables with `attrs`.

I was more perplex that the use of `attr.asdict()` is not smoothly available at each dotted subvariable such that `mlle` and `mlle.list_of_list_of_elements[0]` works, but not the `mlle.list_of_list_of_elements` in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr.asdict` takes an instance of an `attr.s`-decorated class. `mlle` and `mlle.list_of_list_of_elements[0]` are both instances of `attr.s`-decorated classes. `mlle.list_of_list_of_elements` is not.

Comment: Thank you for the concise explaination; is there any way to continue to use `attrs` on a `list`-type in a Pythonise-manner?